# using wp_authenticate() to redirect certain users when logging in

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

Our website is using Wordpress - WooCommerce login page for customers to login.

I am trying to use [wp_authenticate()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/) to achieve the following:

1) Customer login to our new website, enter their username and password, and hit Login button. In case you want to see WooCommerce Login file, click [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/myaccount/form-login.php).

2) Our new website goes through list see if the username matches.  If the username matches, don't even look at the password, just redirect the user to other url such as google.com

3) if the username doesn't match with our list, just let them login as usual.

With JQuery, someone helped me to come up with the following code:

```
var names = new Array(”BILL”, ”JIM”, ”BOB”); // get all names into array, and all in uppercase
var dest_url = ”http://www.website.com”; // URL we want to send them to
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(”input[name=’login’]”).click(function(event){
event.preventDefault(); // prevent default form action
var current_name = jQuery(”#username”).val();
current_name = current_name.trim().toUpperCase();
if ( -1 != jQuery.inArray(current_name, names) ) {
alert(”Redirecting ” + current_name + ” to ” + dest_url);
window.location = dest_url; // send to desired URL
}
else
document.getElementsByClassName(”login”)[0].submit(); // input name not on our list, so just do normal submit action
});
});
```

But I am not sure if wp_authenticate() can actually contain jquery script inside.  Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We split up our website, and our customers are elderly people and they have no idea what they are doing.  we want to make it as less complicated as possible by letting them login to our website as usual, but this time, those in our list should be redirected to the other website. These people probably don't know which website they should visit after the split up.

Comment: These people in the list would be qualified for certain insurance program and education because they live in a specific State.  So, they need to go to our new website (which we are currently building right now) Our old website will still talk about insurance stuff available on Federal gov level.  I just mentioned "google" simply because I didn't really want to mention the real url of our new website which is under construction.  I wouldn't actually redirect user to google out of no where.  Let me know if you have more questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend doing this in PHP, not javascript.

Second, you have a couple of options, leveraging the built-in functionality of WordPress.

If all you care about is the username, and do not care if they successfully logged in with the right password, then you could leverage the filter found in [wp_authenticate()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/)

```
// This is the filter wp_authenticate fires
apply_filters( 'authenticate', null, $username, $password );
```

Knowing that, you could write a quick little plugin, or add this code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
// Run this filter with priority 9999 (last, or close to last), after core WP filters have run
add_filter('authenticate', 'redirect_certain_users', 9999, 3);

// Your custom filter function
function redirect_certain_users( $user, $username, $password) {
    // Assumes you write a function called get_list_of_users_to_redirect that returns an array similar to that in your sample code
    $redirect_users = get_list_of_users_to_redirect();

    // If the user is in the array of users to redirect, then send them away
    if ( in_array( $username, $redirect_users ) ) {
        header("location:http://www.example.com");
        die();
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Note that this code is untested, but should get you at least 90% of the way there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Would simple array/return like: function get_list_of_users_to_redirect() {$mylist = array("jim49", "amyjones", "james_ab", "insurcorp");return $mylist;} will work to get the list of users? or can I simply replace $redirect_users = get_list_of_users_to_redirect(); with an unindexed array such as $redirect_users = array("jim49", "amyjones", "james_ab", "insurcorp");  

I am sorry, I am new to php.

Comment: I just used the unindexed array to make it simple by writing the following code in functions.php file located at my child theme folder.    add_filter('authenticate', 'redirect_certain_users', 9999, 3);
function redirect_certain_users( $user, $username, $password) {
    $redirect_users = array("jim49");
    if ( in_array( $username, $redirect) ) {
        header("location:http://www.example.com");
        die();
    }
    return $user;
}  Though, i think it is not recognizing the array. I entered jim49 as login username and password as whatever, but still says Invalid username.

Comment: Tested - works, but there was a typo in the `in_array($username, $redirect)` line - should read `in_array($username, $redirect_users)`

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix the typo.  It is now tested, and known to work properly.