# using wp_authenticate() to redirect certain users when logging in with email

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect

Our new website is using Wordpress - WooCommerce login page for customers to login.

I have the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832291/using-wp-authenticate-to-redirect-certain-users-when-logging-in) which allows me to redirect some customers to old website based on their username.  Though, the following code only works for username and not email address.

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'redirect_certain_users', 9999, 3);

// Your custom filter function
function redirect_certain_users( $user, $username, $password) {
    // Assumes you write a function called get_list_of_users_to_redirect that returns an array similar to that in your sample code
    $redirect_users = array("jim49", "amyjones", "james_ab", "insurcorp");

    // If the user is in the array of users to redirect, then send them away
    if ( in_array( $username, $redirect_users) ) {
        header("location:http://www.example.com");
        die();
    }
    return $user;
}
```

I am trying to see if there is a way for customers to enter their email address and still be able to get redirected like above code?